# Assigning values to attributes different than the option?

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, custom-attributes

Is it possible in magento that if you set a attribute to be used in admin (the customer doesn't need to see this) that you can set a different value to be saved other than that is set as the option?

Best way I can describe what I'm trying to achieve is imagine you were doing a dropdown option in a html form for example

```
<option value="32">Size S</option>
  <option value="34">Size M</option>
  <option value="36">Size L</option>
  <option value="38">Size XL</option>
```

So imagine the attribute Option would be size S but I want it to record the value as 32

That way the site admin could read the attribute correctly  and select Size S as the option but for export purposes when you export via the dataflow profile it will export the value as 32 (as that is the value that is saved)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a custom source model for your `size` attribute.
This way you can control the value (id) of the options not just the label. 
[Here is a tutorial](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2012/11/product-attribute-with-custom-options.html) on how to create an attribute with custom source.

What you need to change in the tutorial is `Easylife_Provider_Model_Attribute_Source_Provider::getAllOptions()` method (of course feel free to change the name of the class also).  For you it should look something like this:

```
public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = false){
    if (is_null($this->_options)){
        $this->_options = array();
        $this->_options[] = array('label'=> $this->__('S'), value=>32);
        $this->_options[] = array('label'=> $this->__('M'), value=>34);
        $this->_options[] = array('label'=> $this->__('L'), value=>36);
        $this->_options[] = array('label'=> $this->__('XL'), value=>38);
    }
    $options = $this->_options;
    if ($withEmpty) {
        array_unshift($options, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>''));
    }
    return $options;
}
```

because you already have the attribute, you won't need the install script

Instead of `$this->addAttribute(...)`
you need this:

```
$this->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'size', 'source_model', '[module]/attribute_source_provider')
```

If you change the class name, make sure you change it in the script above.

There is only one flaw with this approach.
You cannot manage the options from the UI. They are hard coded in the source model.
But how often will you change your sizes, right? :)

Anyway., you can overcome this flaw, but creating a simple CRUD module where you can manage the sizes. have something like 'Label', 'value' fields int he add/edit form.

Then you can use the values in the table for your new CRUD module to generate the options in the method mentioned above.

Comment: Marius, your solution is definitely the correct approach.  I just like to present options that don't require programming depending upon the skill level of the individual asking the question.  However, it's one of those risky approaches as to not harm the Magento community by presenting a less than appropriate solution.

Comment: @Rob i didn't say ypor solution is bad. It is actually interesting. I just said it might not solve the problem. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Not sure this would be feasible. You say about not changing sizes often but actually it would be quite often. The reason for this is that depending on the brand we are selling they have their own interpretation of what size S is in inches. So we would need to add in like XXX - Small -> 32   , YYY- Small -> 32

Comment: @Deadgoodundies. You might be right, but I offered a solution in case you don't want to hard code the values. You create a CRUD module where you manage your sizes and int he source model use the values from that table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess what you are looking to do is to use this feature in Magento. You can display on the frontend different than the admin and export user.   What you do is set the admin value to "32" and the front end display value for your store to "Size Small"[image]  I may have misread your request and have these backwards for your intent, but give it a try. This is located as seen here:

[image]

Comment: Ha...nice workaround. This might be useful in some cases, but I think the problem is with the export. when exporting products you see the actual id of the option selected for size (that can be anything and has no meaning). I think the op wants the option id to be 32, 34 and so on not the label.

Comment: Yes that is correct so for example in admin when I chose something from the dropdown it would say XXX - Small but when it comes to export time the value it exports would be 32 . Reason for this is that it's not for importing back into magento , rather importing into a different system for selling on other channels where conversion to the the numerical value is needed